# mysql UNION query output

Tags: mysql, sql

my English is not very good, but i try to explain my self clear. i need advice.
i am selecting from one table sum of values of each field.
and my query looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT SUM(Clicks) AS  sales , 'sales' as type
 FROM ClicksPerDay
 WHERE BannerID = 3456

 UNION

 SELECT SUM(Clicks) AS  rent, 'rents' as type
 FROM ClicksPerDay
 WHERE BannerID = 3457
) total
```

output that i have is :

```
sales | type
 23   | rents
 26   | sales
```

and i need it like this:

```
 sales | rents
   26  |  23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(BannerId = 3456, Clicks, 0) ) AS  sales,
    SUM( IF(BannerId = 3457, Clicks, 0) ) AS  rents
FROM ClicksPerDay
WHERE BannerID IN (3456, 3457)
```

Comment: can you explain pls what `IF(BannerId = 3456, Clicks, 0) )` means?? i don't really understand what is `0` mean? thank you.

Comment: @Viktorino `0` is the `else` condition for `IF()` call. You can read about the syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT sales = SUM(sales), rent = SUM(clicks) FROM
(
 SELECT SUM(Clicks) AS  sales , 0 as rent
 FROM ClicksPerDay
 WHERE BannerID = 3456

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 0 as sales, SUM(Clicks) AS  rent
 FROM ClicksPerDay
 WHERE BannerID = 3457
) total
```

Comment: Although I like hjpotter92's answer quite a lot too; but I lacked the knowledge on the IF() syntax to do it myself =)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cross join - not exactly what it is intended to, but as you only have 2 results, it should work - but you have to omit the "'sales' as type" and "'rents' as type" projection.